# Autocomplete extender is not displaying the list

Tags: asp.net

--aspx code--

```
<asp:TextBox class="txtbx" ID="TextBox4" runat="server" placeholder="Blood Group" 
    onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Blood Group'"
    BackColor="#F8F8F8" 
        ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
        CompletionInterval="100" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
        ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox4" 
        UseContextKey="True">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    <br />
```

--code behind--

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string[] bloodgroup = { "A+", "A-", "A1+", "A1-", "A1B+", "A1B-", "A2+", "A2-", "A2B+", "A2B-", "AB+", "AB-", "B+", "B-", "OH+", "OH-", "O+", "O-", "INRA" };
    var namelist = from tmp in bloodgroup where tmp.ToUpper().StartsWith(prefixText) select tmp;
    return namelist.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: did you keep a debug point in code behind and tried to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use developer tools of the browser and find if your option list is getting populated in HTML. If yes then all you need to do is check z-index of that panel.

Comment: developer tool in the sense??

Comment: Right click on browser window  and select -> Inspect/Inspect element.